# how to pass dataframe column into CommonRegex

Tags: python, regex, pandas

How can we pass a datafarme column into commonregex libraray and hide data if it matches with regex value

```
    from commonregex import CommonRegex

    address = ['61 Park Street, Camden, ME, 04843, US', '1208 BEECHCRAFT BLVD','6704 BEECHCRAFT', 'PO BOX 469', '6461 44TH AVE' , '11026 BELLE HAVEN DR']
    df = pd.DataFrame(address, columns = ['Address'])
    parser = CommonRegex()
    parser.street_addresses(df.Address)
```

It throws error

```
 ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().


df['new'] = df.Address.apply(lambda x: next(iter(parser.street_addresses(x)), ''))
print (df)
                                 Address                  new
0  61 Park Street, Camden, ME, 04843, US      XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
1                   1208 BEECHCRAFT BLVD                     
2                        6704 BEECHCRAFT                     
3                             PO BOX 469                     
4                          6461 44TH AVE        XXXXXXXXXXXXX
5                   11026 BELLE HAVEN DR  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
df['new'] = df.Address.apply(parser.street_addresses)
```

Or:

```
df['new'] = df.Address.apply(lambda x: parser.street_addresses(x))
```

Or `list comprehension`:

```
df['new'] = [parser.street_addresses(x) for x in df.Address]
```

---

```
print (df)
                                 Address                    new
0  61 Park Street, Camden, ME, 04843, US      [61 Park Street,]
1                   1208 BEECHCRAFT BLVD                     []
2                        6704 BEECHCRAFT                     []
3                             PO BOX 469                     []
4                          6461 44TH AVE        [6461 44TH AVE]
5                   11026 BELLE HAVEN DR  [1026 BELLE HAVEN DR]
```

If want first matched value add `next` with `iter` for possible match default value if empty lists:

```
df['new'] = df.Address.apply(lambda x: next(iter(parser.street_addresses(x)), ''))
print (df)
                                 Address                  new
0  61 Park Street, Camden, ME, 04843, US      61 Park Street,
1                   1208 BEECHCRAFT BLVD                     
2                        6704 BEECHCRAFT                     
3                             PO BOX 469                     
4                          6461 44TH AVE        6461 44TH AVE
5                   11026 BELLE HAVEN DR  1026 BELLE HAVEN DR
```

Or if need join all possible values in lists with separator:

```
df['new'] = df.Address.apply(parser.street_addresses).str.join(', ')
```

Comment: hey @jezrael how can i hide the data with X if it parses it like whole address should be marked XXXXX

Comment: @ParthTiwari - Can you add to question expected output? Not sure if understand

Comment: @ParthTiwari - There is some logic for number of X? Or there should be e.g. `XXXXX` ?

Comment: the whole address should be XXXXX

Comment: @ParthTiwari - Use `df['new'] = np.where(df.Address.apply(parser.street_addresses).str.len() == 0, '', 'XXXXX')`

Comment: what if i want to apply over address column  [61 Park Street, Camden, ME, 04843, US] whole should be marked XXXXXXX over the same column if matched with regex

Comment: @ParthTiwari - Sorry, not understand.